# PHP and AJAX - internal error 500

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I am trying to make a simple AJAX calling in PHP and have a problem with **Internal error 500**. When I click on the link, so the data are successfully loaded - this I see through FireBug, but I got the error above. It's on localhost.
When I try to set to the URL of a browser the address, that is called by AJAX, so the content is successfully loaded.

Where I should start to search the problem - or what could be wrong?

**EDIT**: in apache log is nothing weird, looks fine.

Comment: First of all, if you have access to server logs, check them for a more detailed description of the error. It might be connected to request headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after checking your php error log you don't find any issues, could it be your javascript AJAX call expects results to be returned in a specific format like JSON?

If this is the case, you need PHP to set the correct content type header when it is responding to the AJAX call, like so:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

So in context, this might look something like:

```
$some_data = array(
  'user_id' => 47,
  'first_name' => 'Mike',
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($some_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the PHP error logs, or perhaps even your web server's error log.

Or if your script spews out errors to the client (which it hopefully doesn't do, at least not in production), try taking a look at the response in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a bug in your PHP. It doesn't matter if it is an AJAX call. Look at your server logs.